# Java StackOverflowError modular exponentiation

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, cryptography

I have this function to calculate modular exponentiation in Java, but due to an excessive recursion for [BigIntegers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) with 2048 and 4096 bits, I have a StackOverflowError.
I don't get this error with BigIntegers with 1024 or 512 bits.

```
public BigInteger expMod(BigInteger n, BigInteger a, BigInteger t)
{
    // case t = 0
    BigInteger res;
    if  (t.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        res = BigInteger.ONE;

    }

    // case t =1
    else if (t.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
         res = a.mod(n);

    }
    // case t even
    else if (t.mod(BigInteger.TWO).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
         res = expMod(n,a.pow(2).mod(n), t.divide(BigInteger.TWO)).mod(n);
    }
    // case t odd
    else {
         res = a.multiply(expMod(n,a.pow(2).mod(n), (t.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(BigInteger.TWO)))).mod(n);
    }
    return res;

}
```

Is there a solution to avoid this?

Comment: The simplest solution would be `a.modPow(t, n)`

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself: replace the recursion with iteration (i.e. a loop): `while (!t.equals(BigInteger.One)) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: You could increase the stack-zip of the java VM

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to replace this method with `a.modPow(t, n)`.

If you want to implement it yourself you can replace the recursion with a `while` loop:

```
public BigInteger expMod(BigInteger n, BigInteger a, BigInteger t) {
    // case t = 0
    BigInteger res;
    if  (t.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        res = BigInteger.ONE;
    }

    // case t =1
    else if (t.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        res = a.mod(n);
    }

    // other: t > 1
    else {
        res = BigInteger.ONE;
        while (!t.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (t.testBit(0)) {  // if bit 0 is set then t must be odd
                res = res.multiply(a).mod(n);
            }
            a = a.multiply(a).mod(n);
            t = t.shiftRight(1);  // shiftRight(1) is the same as division by 2 but probably faster
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```